# mapping <leader>; and <leader>, to ; and , respectively

Tags: key-bindings, leader

My `<leader>` key is `,` and for convenience I'm using for a few years now the `;` normal-mapped as a `:`, to save me a key stroke to type `:commands`.

Now, I know that `,` and `;` are shortcuts themselves, to repeat last `f` and `F` commands and the inverse.

```
; and ,         Repeat latest f, t, F or T [count] times. See :help cpo-;
```

I want to map them to be `<leader> ;` and `<leader> ,`, so I don't lose this functionality. So, if I type `,;` it will act as `;` and `,,` will do as a single `,`. I can't wrap my head around this mapping.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

---

edited:

I have the following configurations/maps:

```
let mapleader=',' 
nnoremap ; :
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply need to create this mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>, ,
nnoremap <leader>; ;
```

OP mentions `<leader>` is comma, via `let mapleader = ','` or similar.

Comment: Thanks! It worked as a charm. So simple, and yet I couldn't make it at first attempt.